# Create a page from php

Tags: php

I been designing my page & I hate copying & pasting the same layout. Can't I make a page generator with php? this how i would like it to work.

- blank text field ( where i'm going to write content )
- submit button ( creates a page with the same layout but changes what i wrote in the content text field only)

this is my code

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>test</title>
    </head>

    <body>
    <div class="wrapper">
    <?php include ("php/leftnav.php"); ?> 

    <div class="middle">
    this the only content i want to change <-----------
    </div>

    <?php include ("php/rightnav.php"); ?> 
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

I'm going to use the page generator to create many pages. Where would I start?

Comment: unfortunately StackOverflow has not been built to create code for you or suggest tutorials, but to help you with your existing scripts if you're stuck... suggest you look around the net, then come back when you have created something but need help to get to the next step...

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=php+page+generator

Answer (score 0):

You can use a CMS, like Joomla, Drupal or WordPress.